# Validation soap messages in WCF C#

Tags: c#, validation, wcf

Is it possible to check if some field marked as `[DataContract]` belongs to some list of `String` ?

I mean something like that:

```
[DataContract(possibleValues=someList)]
String value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but you could easily implement [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement the server side validation. See [here](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/validating-wcf-service-operations-using-system.componentmodel.dataannotations) for some examples.

Comment: can you tell my why don't you propose this one: http://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/ ?  Any issues with it ?

Comment: Never used it myself; nor is it an official microsoft library. It could be a great implementation for all I know :)